# Position of cell being edited in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to get the coordinates (row index and column index) of a cell of `JTable` when key is released during editing that cell. I am trying to do it in this way:

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent released) {
    JTable tbl = (JTable)(released.getSource());
    if (tbl.getCellEditor() != null)
        System.out.println(tbl.getSelectedRow()+","+tbl.getSelectedColumn());
}
```

But this does not return position (row index and column index) of cell being edited. Please help.

Comment: This is an odd request and suggests, at least to me, that you may be asking an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution may be to use a completely different approach. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it. Also consider creating and posting a valid [mcve].

Comment: Several issues come to mind, including -- why use a KeyListener in a JTable cell editor? There are usually much better ways to get this information. The other -- are you sure that the source of the KeyListener is the JTable and not the editor object?

Answer (score 3):

> when key is released during editing that cell.

Doesn't make sense. The editor has focus when a cell is being edited. Also the user could use the mouse to put the cell in editing mode.

If you want to know when a cell starts editing you can add a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `JTable`:

```
//
//  Implement the PropertyChangeListener interface
//
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
    {
        //  A cell has started/stopped editing

        if ("tableCellEditor".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
        {
            if (table.isEditing())
                // code for editing started;
            else
                // code for editing stopped;
        }
    }
```

Then you just use the `getSelected...()` methods to get the row/column.

Comment: A decent answer for a not so decent question.